# Copy class instance, inheriting changes from old instance but allowing new changes without modifying it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to clone a class instance, such that the new instance contains any variables changed at the time of copying but other changes can be done to it without retroactively modifying the instance it was copied from. I need to copy `y` from `x` instead of spawning a new `Item` class as the `x` instance contains properties that were modified elsewhere and I want `y` to inherit modified attributes then allow further changes to itself without also affecting `x`.

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
    def change(self, value):
        self.value = value

x = Item()
x.change(0)
print(str(x.value))
y = x
y.change(1)
print(str(x.value) + " - " + str(y.value))
```

The result I get:

```
0
1 - 1
```

The desired result would look like:

```
0
0 - 1
```

Obviously this happens because `y = x` only copies a reference to the existing instance, but what else should I do? All answers I found suggest `copy()` or `deepcopy()` but neither works: Whether I do `y = x.deepcopy()` or `y = deepcopy(x)` I'm told Python has no `copy` / `deepcopy` builtins.

Comment: You need to `import copy` first, and then `copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy` the desired object.

Comment: You just need to import the copy module or the class you want from it e.g., from copy import deepcopy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `import copy` first, and then `copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy` the desired object:

```py
import copy

class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
    def change(self, value):
        self.value = value

x = Item()
x.change(0)
print(str(x.value))
y = copy.copy(x)
y.change(1)
print(str(x.value) + " - " + str(y.value))
```